# A straw poll widget to add CNN-style polls on one's own website or blog

Tags: webapp-rec, blog, javascript

Wufoo.com is very nice (maybe overkill with the features) but it's missing one thing I really want for a simple straw poll:  when you answer the straw poll question, the question itself should disappear and be replaced with the results (some simple statistics about how many people answered what).
This is how sidebar polls on sites like CNN.com work.

Do you know of a tool for that?

Answer (score 2):

[PollDaddy](http://polldaddy.com/) does this. Once you sign-up and create a poll you'll be given embed codes for different sites. If your blog is hosted on Wordpress.com, choose the Wordpress option, otherwise use the javascript embed snippet.

Comment: Thanks Simon, PollDaddy looks good.  But it allows very few responses before charging a ton of money.  I bet there's an open source equivalent somewhere.  Anyone have ideas?

Comment: The 100 response limit is for surveys, not polls.

Comment: Oh, in that case I'm inclined to stick to PollDaddy. Thanks again, Simon!  (You're sure no limit on poll responses?)

Comment: If there were significant limits, they'd mention them on the plans page. http://polldaddy.com/pricing/

Comment: Hmm, they say "100 survey responses per month" and don't mention poll responses so I kind of assumed "survey responses" included poll responses, but maybe you're right.

Comment: On the dashboard they clearly separate surveys and polls.

Answer (score 1):

I use **[Addpoll](http://www.addpoll.com)** to create online surveys, forms and polls. Offers me great account with detailed reports, unique design, exporting, easy sharing and more.

There is an option that you can enable, so the user sees results, either by percentage or as vote count. Scroll to the end of the **[Create Poll help page](https://www.addpoll.com/help/read/createPoll)** to see an example. I don't know if this is available under the free usage plan, you'll need to check on that.

Comment: Joe, have you used the straw poll widget from Addpoll? Does it display in the sidebar, and with what sort of statistics? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Pollhost.com](http://www.pollhost.com/).    It's another site that does free polls with embedable code snippets for your site.